# Change axis of hinge joint by script in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to simulate car turning with `HingeJoint` (or configurable joint) in Unity game engine.

I have 4 wheels attached to main body with the joints what works well. Now I need to change the joints axis (relative to main body) with a controller script to make the wheels turn. It does what I need if I change the Z value of axis in inspector (rotating the axis relative to main body), but when I try to change the Z axis in script, things get crazy. Seems to me that the axis is relative to parent body before you run the game, but when you run it, the axis maybe gets absolute or something.

I was trying to find answer for quite some time, but I was not able to find anything related to the axis.

Only thing I found is about `TargetRotation` (on configurable joint), what is actually not what I am looking for because I believe that you need to set some limits in another axis to make it work, thus making the already springy joints wobble even more. Obviously, I need the result act as rigid as possible.
Still if you have some idea how to do that with `TargetRotation` let me know please, because I was not yet even able to recognize how it actually works.

I believe the question is quite simple, but if you feel that the question is not clear enough let me know so I'll add some pictures for better explanation.

EDIT:
Well, adding some more info was suggested so here we go:

Here is what I have
[image]

As u see its simple box with 4 cylinders attached to the box with configurablejoints. All elements are on the same root level and have rigidbodies attached.

In red circles u can see different axle rotations made by changing axis Z values (from -1 to 1) in inspector, what is exactly what I need to do by script to steer the vehicle.

Unfortunatelly when I add axis Z controller in script like that:

```
        float steering = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        configurableJoint.axis = new Vector3(configurableJoint.axis.x, configurableJoint.axis.y, steering);
```

It breaks like this:
[image]

So what I would like is some idea how such function could be achieved, as well as someone who can explain me how the axes of joints work would be nice.

Thanks in advance for any effort

Comment: Do add some more information regarding the behavior you are seeing, screenshots and code snippets will help other people to assist you.

Comment: I really don't think Hinge joints can be used in that way you know man? It's just not what they are for, at all.  Quite simply, you just "use a transform". ie the wheel assembly is a child of the chassis.  that's all there is to it.  (just `.Rotate` the child transform - no big deal.

Comment: It's worth noting that it is incredibly complicated engineering to build a car rig - it takes 1-2 man years of work.  Pretty much every car project in Unity just uses the famous "Edy's Vehicle Physics" from the asset store (or one of Edy's new competitors!!)  It's so difficult there are really no wiki, community, etc efforts out there. On top of that it completely changed w/ Unity 5 since they totally changed "wheel colliders" (which used to be incredibly bizarre and are now merely bizarre).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you would need to parent the wheels to the body of the car, and then rotate the wheels relative to the car body in your script.

It would help if you could provide a simple Unity project that could be downloaded, experimented with, and tweaked in order to duplicate the problem and fix it.  I'm happy to help out if you want to send a simple demonstration of the problem so I can try to fix it.